# How can I use the IP Address and Domain Restrictions module for only one website on an IIS 10 server with multiple websites?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2016, iis-10

does anyone know if there is a way to use the IP Address and Domain Restrictions module on only one website in IIS 10?

My IIS server has 12 different websites, but I only need to restrict one to domain traffic only.

I don't see anywhere in the module that allows me to target a website.

It seems like any rules would apply to all the websites being hosted on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Find a good book to study IIS configuration system please. Then you know how to achieve site level configuration with mechanisms such as location tags, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8#location-tags Even in Microsoft's example (carefully check out the screen shots), only the Default Web Site is configured, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions Not any other site on the same server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the site you want to apply restrictions to from the sites node on the left.

One of the icons in the middle pane is `IP Address and Domain Restrictions`, anything you change here only applies to this site only.

You can even select a directory under site and only apply restrictions to this specific directory.

This is true for most settings in IIS.